# PyCharm import file in the same directory

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2020.1 on Linux. I have an import statement like this:

```
from model import *
```

and PyCharm marks the word model with a red underscore and error message "Unresolved reference 'model'".

Folder Structure:

```
project
├── ...
├── Chapter6
│   └── FoolBox
│       ├── attack.py   <-- this is where i want to run the code
│       ├── data.py
│       └── model.py    <-- this is the file i want to import in 'attack.py'
├── Chapter7
├── ...
```

When i run the code though it runs without any problems. How can i fix this faulty behaviour of PyCharm ?

Comment: What's the folder structure of your project?

Comment: Have you configured your project interpreter correctly?

Comment: @jfaccioni i edited the question to include the folder structure

Comment: @MachineLearner i have installed every neccessary dependency, like tensorflow and foolbox with "pip install" and there are no error messages about them. The error messages are only when i import another file in the same directory. Not sure how to configure the interpreter any more, any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm you need to right-click the root folder (e.g., `project`) and select:

`Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`

Comment: It did not work when i marked the 'project' folder as sources root, but when i marked the 'FoolBox' project as sources root it got fixed. Thank you!